# Cursor.execute does not work in Python

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I am using `MySQLdb` package in Python to update my database. I have a simple update command as follows :

```
update_query = "update user_details set `address`='%s' where `id`='%s'"
cursor.execute(update_query, (address, id1))
print(cursor._last_executed)
```

Here is the command executed :

```
update user_details set `address`='35, Chikmagalur' where `id`='242069'
```

The program runs fine without error. However, the database is not getting updated. The same command works when I run as an SQL query on PHPMyAdmin.

Any idea what could be the issue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is a duplicate of ...

sql transactions needs to be committed, either explicitly or implicitly.

either issue a commit command explicitly 
    cursor._get_db().commit()

setting the connection to autocommit when opening the connection is also an option.

Comment: I have enabled autocommit. Here is the code : db = MySQLdb.connect(host=host, port=port, user=username, passwd=password, db=database, cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
    db.autocommit = True
    cursor = db.cursor() But it doesnt work either

Comment: you can see the number of effected rows, print(cursor.execute(update_query, (address, id1)))

Comment: It says 1 ( 1 row is affected ). However there is no change in the table whasover. Strange

Comment: @kiran: check if the db you are checking in is same as the one used in the code

Comment: cursor._get_db().commit() worked. However autocommit was enabled to true. Thanks @sinaiy for the help